# proc в linux на ассемблере и компиляция нескольких файлов

Tags: linux, ассемблер, fasm

решил сделать набор файлов, где будет уже заранее реализовано набор функций, чтобы их потом не писать. но вот проблема. в linux я не могу использовать `proc`. я видел в одном каталоге используется макрос, но не ужели без макроса невозможно использовать `proc`? в windows работает `proc` без проблем. хотя может там тоже макрос. я так понимаю что мне придется делать с помощью меток и делать их публичными. в общем помогите. если proc нельзя, то как сделать правильно, чтобы у меня были отдельные файлы и я мог создавать типа многофайловые программы. я компилировал так `fasm bf.asm bf; chmod +x bf`. но думаю это не правильно. наверное надо каждый файл превратить в `*.o` и потом с помощью `ld` создать программу. а если я хочу сишные функции использовать в коде, то что мне нужно будет макрос `proc` использовать, как примере от fasm дается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> я видел в одном каталоге используется макрос, но не ужели без макроса
> невозможно использовать `proc`

Без макросов нельзя использовать `proc`, но можно обойтись и без `proc`. Вообще, можно попробовать использовать `proc32.inc` или `proc64.inc` из пакета fasm для windows.

> я компилировал так `fasm bf.asm bf; chmod +x bf`. но думаю это не правильно.

Это НЕ не правильно - это просто один из вариантов. fasm позволяет создавать и сразу готовые исполняемые файлы, и объектные файлы, и голые бинарные файлы - тип получаемого файла задается с помощью директивы `format`. Как вам нужно так и делайте.

> наверное надо каждый файл превратить в `*.o` и потом с помощью `ld` создать программу. а если я хочу сишные функции использовать в коде, то что мне нужно будет макрос `proc` использовать, как примере от fasm дается?

Если собираетесь использовать функции libc, то нужно будет в исходнике прописывать, что вам нужен объектный файл (`format ELF64` или `ELF` без `executable`), потом линковать со стандартной библиотекой (см. пример `examples/libcdemo` в пакете fasm для linux). `proc` вообще ни при чем, без него можно обойтись.

Возможно будет полезно, на форуме flatassembler есть раздел с часто задаваемыми вопросами по программированию под linux: [About Fasm programming in Linux & FAQs](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=6365)